# Notepad in windows form application

Tags: c#, winforms

I have some string in my string variable. When I clicking open button in my Winform application it opens the notepad with that string. The notepad should created temporarily. If i closed the notepad, it should permanently deleted.

For example when I click "open" button the string "Result" value generated and the notepad should displayed with result string value.

Answer (score 6):

This should demonstrate how to open Notepad and *put* text into it.

> This is a simple example of starting a Notepad process and then adding text to it.
>   Will open a new Notepad.exe process and then add the text "Sending a message, a message from me to you" to the text area of notepad.
>
> The constant 0x000c of SendMessage  is documented here  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms632644(v=vs.85).aspx .
>   The constant says SETTEXT which really means that the text in notepad will be replaced if you send more than one message using this constant.

Sourced from: http://www.peterhenell.se/msg/C---AddSend-text-to-notepad-process-using-user32dll-SendMessage-from-your-application

```
using System;
using System.Text;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System.Diagnostics;

namespace SendMessageTest
{
    class Program
    {
        [DllImport("user32.dll", EntryPoint = "FindWindowEx")]
        public static extern IntPtr FindWindowEx(IntPtr hwndParent, IntPtr hwndChildAfter, string lpszClass, string lpszWindow);

        [DllImport("User32.dll")]
        public static extern int SendMessage(IntPtr hWnd, int uMsg, int wParam, string lParam);



        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            DoSendMessage("Sending a message, a message from me to you");
        }



        private static void DoSendMessage(string message)
        {
            Process notepad = Process.Start(new ProcessStartInfo("notepad.exe"));
            notepad.WaitForInputIdle();

            if (notepad != null)
            {
                IntPtr child = FindWindowEx(notepad.MainWindowHandle, new IntPtr(0), "Edit", null);
                SendMessage(child, 0x000C, 0, message);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I've edited your answer to include a direct quote from your blog where you got this program from. If this is against your intention, feel free to revert. I felt that it needed a little more explanation.